# Using JQuery to resize and realign images doesn't work on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, preloader, masonry

So I am relatively inexperienced with Jquery. What I did was purchase a wordpress theme from theme forest and it has a portfolio section which is supposed to work either as a masonry or grid layout. Neither of which load correctly on first load. The theme uses the Isotope, and I think this link explains what needs to be done: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#imagesloaded

Below is the code that I think calls this function, and the site can be viewed here https://www.roseryflowers.com/bridal-gallery/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
/*--  Portfolio --*/
if ($('.portfolio-items').length > 0) {
    $container = $('.portfolio-items');
    $container.isotope({filter: '.element'});
    $(window).trigger('resize');
    $('.portfolio-links a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $this.parents('.portfolio-links').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.parent().addClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');

        var selector = $this.attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope( {filter: selector} );
    });
}
```

I am at a loss for what to do here. Any help would be appreciated. I even implemented a preloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `imagesloaded.js` file from your page and change the line with

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

to

```
$(window).load(function(){ $(window).trigger('resize'); });
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. I have tested it on FF, IE and Chrome after clearing the cache and so far so good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Isotope's documentation

> Unloaded images can throw off Isotope layouts and cause item elements
>   to overlap. imagesLoaded resolves this issue. imagesLoaded works by
>   triggering a callback after all child images have been loaded.
>
> initialize Isotope after all images have loaded

```
var $container = $('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
 $container.isotope({
    //options
  });
});
```

This could be the problem

There is a little bit more about...

EDIT

your wrapper tag is ".portfolio-items" then try this

```
var $container = $('.portfolio-items').imagesLoaded(function () {

  if ($('.portfolio-items').length > 0) {
    $container = $('.portfolio-items');
    $container.isotope({ filter: '.element' });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
    $('.portfolio-links a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $this.parents('.portfolio-links').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.parent().addClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');

        var selector = $this.attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    });
  }
});
```

You need to be sure to add ImagesLoaded to your project https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: I saw that but not sure how to execute that into the code I posted.

Comment: Didn't do the trick. It still just loads them all overlapped on first load.